# Load plugin from specific location

Tags: emacs

In my computer I have an Emacs plugin installed with the Debian package system, but this plugin is obsolete and I'm trying to install it inside my home directory with package-install. I have installed a newer version, but if I check which version is loaded, the older one is.

I tried with `load-file` and the global path to the new version, but it still loads the old version.

How can I force the load of the new one? Please, imagine that I'm not the sysadmin of the computer and I cannot uninstall any software package.

Comment: Does the library you're trying to load comprise just a single file? or are there multiple files?

Comment: Also, it would help if you specified which library (and debian package) you are referring to.

Comment: The library is "yasnippet". The old one has only one file (0.6), and the new one has multiple files (I have installed it via package-install on Emacs 24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a library contains multiple files one can assume that a single main file will load the others as necessary; but if the directory isn't in the `load-path` then it won't be able to load them (or at least not those versions), so `load-file` on its own isn't going to do the trick.

I don't make much use of package.el myself, but I'd really have thought that it would manage the load-path such that it took precedence over anything in `site-lisp` (which is presumably where the debian package is installing things.)

Try running `emacs --no-site-lisp` and check that the correct version of the library is loaded. If you don't want anything from the site libraries, then that might even be your solution.

If that works, then check the `load-path` variable after starting Emacs normally. Unless an absolute path is given, Emacs will look at those directories in sequence, and use the first one which matches. I am guessing that for some reason your site-lisp directory is appearing before the one created by package.el.

Or perhaps the package didn't install correctly at all.

That all said, in Emacs 24.3 at least `(package-initialize)` is called automatically and I don't think you should need to manually load anything. Check the `package-load-list` variable.

**Edit:**

On that last note, refer to [cannot open load dired-details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512884/cannot-open-load-dired-details/17513285#17513285).

At the time I hadn't noticed that Emacs doesn't initialize packages until *after* the user init file has loaded, so you generally *will* need to initialize them manually in your init file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: I checked the value of `load-path` and it has an absolute path first, pointing to the downloaded version instead the site-lisp one. I have a lot of paths in the `load-path`, but all the home-based are before the dpkg's based paths. In addition, the `package-load-list` variable is set to `(all)`, so I cannot figure what the problem is...

Comment: What does `M-x locate-library RET yasnippet RET` tell you?

Comment: It says that the library is located on my home directory (the package-install version!), but `M-x yas/about` sais that 0.6.1b version (the Debian package one) is installed

Comment: When you ran `emacs --no-site-lisp` did it use the package-install version?

Comment: With `--no-site-lisp` I get an error `File error: Cannot open load file, yasnippet`. That is very estrange!

Comment: I suspect something is attempting to load yasnippet *before* the package initialisation takes place. Run `emacs --no-site-lisp --debug-init`. As an error was thrown, that should get you a backtrace which will tell you where it's happening.

Comment: I did it already: after comment another system-installed plugin that has failed due to the `--no-site-lisp` option, I get this error loading my `yasnippet.cfg` file: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "yasnippet")
  require(yasnippet)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-35807> nil "/home/xjosseg/.emacs.d/configs/yasnippet.cfg" nil t)  ; ...` In addition, the yasnippet path has disappeared from my `load-path` variable. I think it is caused by the `---site-lisp`, because Emacs cannot load the `package` plugin, so the `load-path` is not updated correctly...

Comment: I just figured that it cannot be loaded because I tried the old-school `(yas/initialize)`, that has changed to `(yas-global-mode 1)` on 0.8 version. Now, I'm able to use the 0.8.0 version when using the `--no-site-lisp`, but when I run emacs without that option, I get `Symbol's function definition is void: yas-global-mode`, so I think it is trying to load first the 0.6.1 version

Comment: That will be for the same reason -- you're trying to do it before package initialisation has happened. Either that, or it's failing to initialise the package. Disable your `yasnippet.cfg` file (that's a strange name for an elisp file, incidentally), and then find out if yasnippet is available after Emacs starts.

Comment: Maybe it is a mess, but yasnippet.cfg is only a fragmented configuration file. I usually fragment my .emacs to control the changes on it more accurately. I commented it the `load` of `yasnippet.cfg` (so, no `require yasnippet` is done theorycally), but yasnippet is loaded with the Debian version (0.6.1).

Comment: No, *keep* the `--no-site-lisp` argument. You still haven't verified that the package version has *ever* been functional. Let Emacs load with no site-lisp and nothing in your custom config trying to load it, and then manually call `M-x yas-global-mode` (or whatever is supposed to be available) and see if it works. If not, you need to find how to fix that before worrying about conflicts with the other version.

Comment: I run `emacs --no-site-lisp` after commenting the load of some plugins. After that, apparently Yasnippet was not loaded by default, but doing `M-x yas-global-mode` it works and load the package-based version (0.8.0)...

Comment: I just found a file `/etc/emacs/site-start.d/50yasnippet.el` that apparently loads Yasnippet from the site-lisp path. Could be that the problem?

Comment: Well that sounds quite likely. Without seeing any of the code I can't say exactly what to do, but I imagine that either `site-start.el` or `default.el` is looking for and loading the files in that `site-start.d` directory; so look for either of those two files somewhere in the load path directories. If `site-start.el` is the culprit (and doesn't provide some way or circumventing individual libraries), you may have to stick with using `--no-site-lisp`. If it's `default.el`, that one loads *after* your own init file, and you can disable it with `(setq inhibit-default-init t)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @philis. I just commented out the lines on the `/etc/emacs/site-start.d/50yasnippet.el`. I don't like so much this option because it disables yasnippet for the rest of users, but it's better than removing Debian yasnippet package. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(defun please-load-my-stuff ()
  (interactive)
  (load "PATH-TO-STUFF/STUFF))
```

When having access to init, put just form "(load ...)" there.
If more than one file is needed, `load-path` must be set also that way - before load, so the other required files are accessible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not an Emacs configuration expert, as you can figure for my question... where do I need to put that code into? I suppose that it goes to my `.emacs` file, doesn't it? And from where do I "call" this function?