# cannot open load dired-details

Tags: emacs, dired

I just installed the emacs package `dired-details` from inside emacs via

```
M-x package-list-packages
```

clicked on the package name and then `install` in the newly opened buffer.

Then I put those lines into my `.emacs`:

```
(require 'dired-details)
(setq-default dired-details-hidden-string ">---< ")
(dired-details-install)
```

When I restart `emacs`, I get the following error:

```
File error: Cannot open load file, dired-details
```

The interesting thing is, that when I mark the code region above and apply

```
M-x eval-region
```

everything works as expected.

```
emacs --version
>> GNU Emacs 24.3.1
```

package version:

```
dired-details-20130328.1119
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packages you installed with package.el need to be initialized if you want to access them during emacs initialization.

Add the line

```
(package-initialize)
```

to the very beginning of your .emacs .

Also follow phil's recommendation and  see the variable

```
package-enable-at-startup
```

Comment: Also see the `package-enable-at-startup` variable. Defaulting to not initialising the packages until after reading the init file seems like rather an unfortunate  decision; that must surely trip up a lot of people...

Comment: It certainly tripped me back when 24 was released.  =/

Comment: I see now that the manual does explain this behaviour. See `C-h i g (emacs) Package Installation RET` beginning from "The reason automatic package loading occurs after loading the init file is that user options only receive their customized values after loading the init file, including user options which affect the
packaging system."