# Emacs sometimes can't open load file

Tags: emacs

I'm using emacs, and most of my packages are install using ELPA. Usually this works fine, and all is well. However, there are two packages where my normal

```
(require 'package-name)
(do-stuff-with package-variables)
```

doesn't work. In particular, YAML mode and sr-speedbar.el give me an error "Cannot open load file, " on startup.

The odd thing is that if I open up my .emacs and evaluate this line by hand, it *does* work. So the file exists, is readable, etc., but Emacs can't find it during startup -- only later. I've done some Googling, but nobody seems to have this problem.

Comment: dependenvies? that are loaded/required later on startup?

Comment: No, sr-speedbar is the last thing to be loaded in my `.emacs`.

Comment: I once had an occasion when my `user-emacs-directory` wasn't defined and a few packages didn't get recognized, so that might be an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probable duplicate of [cannot open load dired-details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512884/cannot-open-load-dired-details)

Add the line

```
(package-initialize)
```

to the very beginning of your .emacs .

Or see the variable

```
package-enable-at-startup
```

Comment: Ah. Wouldn't havae expected that behavior. Thanks!